# Why should load class from on demand modules(Dynamic modules) firstly in the callback of SplitInstallManager?

Tags: android, kotlin-reflect

Recently, I'm doing a feature based on Dynamic Modules, and I want to load a class from dynamic modules. Since base app can't access class in dynamic module, I use direct reflection to do this. Below is my reflection code:

```
const val PROVIDER_CLASS= "com.google.android.samples.dynamicfeatures.ondemand.BaseData\$Provider"

fun loadReflection() {
  val moduleProvider = Class.forName(PROVIDER_CLASS).kotlin.objectInstance as Share3dFeature.Provider
}

button.setOnClickListener {
     loadReflection()
}
```

All right in debug mode. However, when I put it in Google Play Store and test the on-demand modules functions, it always crashes when I click button to load reflection class after finishing installing module. And the exceptions are:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/app/***/base.apk (No such file or directory)`

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/app/***/split_config.en.apk (No such file or directory)`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No BuiltInsLoader implementation was found. Please ensure that the META-INF/services/ is not stripped from your application and that the Java virtual machine is not running under a security manager`

Then all right when relaunch app. This crash only occurs at the first time finishing installing module and call reflection code.

After changing many configs about on-demand module, I still can't fix this bug. By accident, I call reflection code in the callback of SplitInstallManager, it won't crash. And I click button to load module is OK.

```
private val listener = SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener { state ->
        when (state.status()) {
            SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED -> {
                Class.forName(PROVIDER_CLASS).kotlin.objectInstance as Share3dFeature.Provider
                toastAndLog("installed version: ${context?.packageManager?.getPackageInfo(requireContext().packageName, 0)?.versionName}")
            }     
        }
    }
```

That's magical, why I should load reflection section firstly in the callback of `SplitInstallManager`?